# Cypher (Neo4j), how to sum a given property through a full path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have been struggling to find a solution to my issue with Cypher..
I am trying to sum a given relationship throughout a path.

For example:
    1 --> 2 --> 3
            --> 4
I want to calculate for node 1 the sum of Amount property for nodes 1,2 3 and 4. (In that case 3 and 4 are both targets of node 2, which i cant manage to represent here)

My understanding is I need to be using collect() and reduce but I still do not get the right answer. I have the following:

```
MATCH (n)-[p]->(m)
WITH m,n, collect(m) AS amounts
RETURN n.ID as Source,m.ID as Target,n.Amount, 
REDUCE(total = 0, tot IN amounts | total + tot.Amount) AS totalEUR
ORDER BY total DESC
```

I get a syntax error, but I am pretty sure even without the syntax error that i will only be summing direct relationships...

Would you guys know if I am on the right path?

Cheers
Max

Answer (score 1):

You need a variable-length relationship in the query:

```
MATCH p = (n)-[*]->(m)
RETURN n.ID as Source, m.ID as Target, n.Amount,
       reduce(total = 0, tot IN nodes(p) | total + tot.Amount) AS totalEUR
ORDER BY totalEUR DESC
```

You can't order by `total` which is a variable local to the `reduce` function.

Note that this will return rows for each path, i.e. `1-->2`, `1-->2-->3`, `1-->2-->3-->4`, `2-->3`, `2-->3-->4`, `3-->4`, since you haven't matched on a specific `n`.

Comment: Hi Frank and thanks for the answer!
I cannot manage to get the sum in the ouput, it is all marked as null. I am wondering whether I might have a data type issue?

Comment: Start by returning the paths (or the first ones, at least, using `LIMIT`) without  the `reduce` part, to see / debug what you are actually matching. As you presented it, the query is awfully generic, I'd supposed you actually had some extra labels and constraints not shown here.